# Create a model that can extract only specific data out of receipts or invoices?

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-recognition, named-entity-recognition, ocr

I'm trying to build a model that is capable of identifying only some of the information on receipts and invoices.

**All the documents having different structure in image format.**

Sample Data :
[Click here](https://www.getharvest.com/downloads/Invoice_Template.pdf)

I have used pypdf2 and pytesseract for text extraction from the receipt but the problem is that just returns all the text from a receipt. Tried to work with regex but as the varieties for documents are different everytime so it is not working in this case.

**Looking on to build a model that returns only a certain fields such as total price, Date, Tax from a receipt.**

I could parse the text to extract by hard coding things but it's not optimal I think. Is there any way to build model for this use case which can identify the required parameters and capture the values. I am looking for something to go on this project.